# Calculate circular shift pairs in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, bit-shift

A [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) moves some of the digits in a number to the beginning of the number, and shifts all other digits forward to the next position. For example, all of the circular shifts of `564` are `564, 645, 456`.

Lets say two numbers of equal length `a` and `b` are *circular pairs* if `a` can become `b` via circular shifting. Using the example above, the circular pairs of `564` are `645` and  `456`.

Given an array of positive integers `nums`, count the number of circular pairs `i` and `j` where `0 <= i < j < len(nums)`

For example, `circular_shifts([13, 5604, 31, 2, 13, 4560, 546, 654, 456])` should return `5`. With the pairs being `(13, 31), (13, 13), (5604, 4560), (31, 13), (546, 654)`.

I wrote a brute force solution that saves all circular shifts of a number in a dictionary `shifts` and for every number `num` in `nums`, I check all the following numbers and if a number `num2` the same digits as `num`, I see if `num2` is in `num`'s circular shifts. If it is then I added this to the total count.

Unfortunately this algorithm runs too slowly and times out, I'm looking for a faster way to solve this problem can anyone think of optimizations, clever tricks, or other strategies to speed this up?

Comment: Can you provide you current try ?

Comment: According to this requirement: `0 <= i < j < len(nums)` pair (5604, 4560) should not be chosen right? len(nums) is by far smaller than `i` or `j` in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very elegant as not much time but the following should be faster as does not repeatedly access the list. Shifting is done on string for simplicity.

```
from collections import Counter

def big(num):
    max = num
    s = str(num)
    for _ in s:
        x = int(s[-1] + s[0:-1])
        if x > max:
            max = x
    return max
        
circs = [big(z) for z in mylist]

c = Counter(circs)

total = 0
for i in c:
    if c[i] > 1:
        total += c[i]
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace every number in the array with its greatest cyclic shift.  1234, for example, would become 4123
2. Count the occurrences of each resulting number
3. If a number occurs n times, that represents n(n-1)/2 cyclic shift pairs.  Add them all up.

Comment: If you can't understand n(n - 1)/2, think of it as handshakes in a group of people. One person can shake hands with n - 1 people (they would not shake their own hand), and the handshake between two people is not counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, where we

1. iterate through the list
2. rotate each number length-1 times
3. and print only if the number is found in the remaining list

```py
    numbers = [13, 5604, 31, 2, 13, 4560, 546, 654, 456]
    # shift_pairs = [(13,31),(13,13),(5604,4560),(31,13),(546,654)]
    pairsFound = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        number = numbers[i]
        length = len(str(number))
        numberToRotate = number
        shift_remaining = length - 1
        temp_list = numbers[i+1:]
        while(shift_remaining >= 0):
            t_remainder = numberToRotate % 10 # 4
            numberToRotate = numberToRotate // 10 # 560
            numberToRotate = numberToRotate + t_remainder * 10 **(length-1) # 4560
            # we should also check for length for cases like 4560, where on a shift we get 456
            if(numberToRotate in temp_list and len(str(numberToRotate)) == length):
                print("({},{})".format(number,numberToRotate))
                pairsFound += 1
            shift_remaining -= 1
    print("no of pairs:", pairsFound)
```

output

```
(13,31)
(13,13)
(5604,4560)
(31,13)
(546,654)
no of pairs: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def big(num):
    max_num = num
    s = str(num)
    for _ in s:
        x = int(s[-1] + s[0:-1])
        if x > max_num:
            max_num = x
        s = s[-1] + s[0:-1]  # Update s for the next iteration
    return max_num
        
mylist = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # Example list
circs = [big(z) for z in mylist]

c = Counter(circs)

total = 0
for i in c:
    if c[i] > 1:
        total += c[i] * (c[i] - 1) // 2
print(total)
```